# Preventing erasure of user data while upgrading iOS application via iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, updates

I want to upload a new beta version of my iOS application for beta testers group. Users save their data in the Documents folder. What do I need to do in order for users to upgrade their application without losing their data?

Comment: Seems programming related to me...

Comment: definitely programming related. Asks directly about deployment of an iPhone application without blasting existing data.

Comment: He's asking that as a developer, what does he have to do to make sure data doesn't get blown away when upgrading the app. This is important for developers to know.

Answer (score 3):

The Documents directory is not overwritten when you update an app so as long as your data is compatible between versions, you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Alternatively, for developers, Xcode's Organizer allows you to extract the contents of an apps Documents directory easily.

Comment: well, the answer was simple - increasing the bundle version. My problem was, that i didn't change the bundle version and when was trying to upgrade the application on iPod it wasn't upgrading without deleting it first, which deleted all user data along with the package.
Increasing bundle version from 1.0 to 1.1 has solved the problem
Thank you anyway for the fast reply.

Comment: while on the mac it updates just fine, on the windows it says - "The application couldn't be updated because it couldn't be verified. iTunes 8.02 for windows... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading iTunes to 7.7 seems solved the problem on Windows