# iPhone Application Version Upgrade will remove file stored in iphone memory?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Currently I have my application in which I am creating some plist file in User's Device and storing some local data.

Now, my confusion is that what happen if i will launch next version of my application and once user will upgrade my application's current version then what happen with that plist file which is stored in Users iPhone Device ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223696/how-the-application-upgrade-works-in-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099747/iphone-what-happens-to-previous-data-when-app-is-upgraded-to-new-version , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941479/upgrading-iphone-application-via-itunes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When users update application only the application bundle changes and other folders in application sandbox should remain intact.So if you store your data in Documents folder then it will persist after application update.
**Edit:** See [Files Saved During Application Updates](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW7) section in "Application Development Guide"

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen to the files stored in the App's Documents directory. They will still be intact after the app is upgraded.