# Does iPhone app updation remove apps Data from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I wanted to know that if i have installed an application in my iPhone and it has a database attached with that which is saved into the particular app folder in iPhone. Now from my application i am updating the database with adding  more records and filling up the database fields.

Now my app has a newer version available. I updated my iphone app. Now does it remove all the database records and create the a new empty database ?? or my all my app personal data will remain there as untouched when app has been updated to newer version.

please guide me friends

Thanks

Comment: I think the database will be replaced for each newer version installed as the database modal can also change.

Comment: can u come up with some for sure comments. because its really important for my project..

Comment: I think you will find the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599217/how-to-maintain-data-in-an-sqlite-database-on-an-iphone-at-a-version-update-of-th) and the documents directory. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that all depends, all the data in the app bundle will be replaced, If you placed your data in the document directory it will be unaffected.

Comment: hmm well i have copied my data into the document directory so it means it wont be affected when app is updated. :) ???